# Relative and Absolute URLS with Directories

Tags: asp.net, url, hyperlink, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm just new to creating and launching web sites and i've hit a stumbling block.

I have a hosting account with 3 different domains assigned to it.  Each domain is mapped to a section of the main directory.  So it goes like this:

```
My Site - 
           -Site1
           -Site2
           -Site3
```

However i can't seem to use the same URLs which work locally on the hosted site and vice versa.  This is an example of the code i use in a link:

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
```

This works fine when uploaded to the host, but locally i get an error:

HTTP Error 404 - Not Found.

And when i leave off the /

```
 <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="About.aspx" Text="About"/>
```

It will work locally but i will get an error when hosted:

> Resource cannot be found: 
>   Requested URL: /Site1/Site1/About.aspx

I've used ~, ../, default.aspx etc and it'll always work on one, but not the other.  I'm sure im missing something dead simple but just can't work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="/ProgectName/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
```

Or
ServerSide

```
Menu1.Items.Add(new MenuItem { NavigateUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("About.aspx"), Text = "About"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, fraid it still doesnt work but if it find a solution i'll post it up.

Comment: Just incase anyone else runs into this, i've worked out the problem.  I was using visual web developer, and as stated above i couldn't use the same paths on my development server as the hosted.  The problem was with the Virtual Path within VWD, on the Solution Explorer, click on the link web site folder itself (icon shows a world), within the properties section change the Virtual Path to /.   I know this is probably obvious but just incase anyone else runs into similar problems!